# Batch For Nest In file and in range

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I need help for Find value from text, then compare match in range list condition goto

File 1.txt contains multiple line:

```
[Software]
App=3
```

I write batch but stuck

```
@ECHO ON
FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS== " %%I IN ('FINDSTR App D:\1.txt') DO
    SET App=%%I
    IF "%App%"=="1" GOTO :1
    IF "%App%"=="2" GOTO :2
    IF "%App%"=="3" GOTO :3

:NOTINRANGE
ECHO Not Found
Exit

:1
ECHO %App%
EXIT

:2
ECHO %App%
EXIT

:3
ECHO %App%
EXIT
```

If %App% value is not in range [1,2,3], i don't know how to write condition

Answer (score 2):

The `set` command must be on the same physical line as the `do`

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example you could do this a couple of different ways because the result of your command is the same as your label names.

You could just execute the `goto` command directly with the result of `FOR` variable.

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS==" %%I IN ('FINDSTR App D:\1.txt') DO goto %%I
```

If you really need to test the range of the value you could still accomplish this without all the extra `IF` comparisons. This assume your app value would never be zero or less than 0.

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS==" %%I IN ('FINDSTR App D:\1.txt') DO IF %%I LEQ 3 GOTO %%I
```